# Why the executable created by pyinstaller doesnot work?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Created an executable using pyinstaller.
its crashing with the below error

```
Failed to extract ..\init_data\*\Readme.txt: failed to open target file!
fopen: Invalid argument
```

there is no Readme.txt in original directory structure. so why is it failing?

The command line is

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "<path_to>\Pack_Movements\*;<path_to>\Pack_Movements\datacreationScripts\utilities\init_data\*" main.py
```

The .spec content is given below

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['<path_to>\\Desktop\\test\\Pack_Movements'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('<path_to>\\Desktop\\test\\Pack_Movements\\*', '<path_to>\\Desktop\\test\\Pack_Movements\\datacreationScripts\\utilities\\init_data\\*')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

The path mentioned in .spec is exactly the same given in command line argument.

Comment: Please include a lot more detail around how you arrived at this error. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: One problem is that `..\init_data\*\Readme.txt` is not a valid filename. What does your `.spec` file look like?

Comment: I have added the command line argument in the original post which I have used to create the executable file.